# literal string does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run an sql script against a test database. I'm getting the error "literal string does not match format string" - weird thing is, a coworker of mine runs the same query on the same test server and is not getting any errors, only when I run it, I get the errors. I'm completely lost on the matter. Where should I go from here?

I'm running my query with SQLPlus command line. I'm receiving the error on the first line: select NVL.....

```
  select NVL(to_char(add_months(to_date(max(mem.birth_date)), + 780), 'yyyymmdd'), ' ')
    into local_turn_65_on
    from member mem
   where mem.member_id in (
         select cmr.member_id
         from case_member cmr
         where cmr.case_id = due_tasks_rec.case_id
           and cmr.current_row_ind = 'Y'
           and cmr.case_member_end_date = 29991231
           and cmr.case_member_role in ('AA','AB','AD','DP'))
     and mem.update_end_date = 29991231
     and mem.birth_date between
         (to_char(add_months(sysdate,-780), 'yyyymmdd'))
     and
         (to_char(add_months(sysdate,-780), 'yyyy') || '1231');
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What data type is `birth_date`? If it's a `date` then replace: `to_date(max(mem.birth_date))` with `max(mem.birth_date)`

Comment: it wont create any difference if its a date by replacing to_date though @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @casper1111 i guess its a procedure/function/block can you post some code above that error also ?

Comment: data type is number(8)

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: if it's a date, then the `to_date()` call should be **removed**, not replaced. Calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date` will create problems like that.

Comment: yeah it should be removed because of unnecessary reconversion of date to again date. But, my ask was does it solve the problem though

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - as the column is actually a number then no; but if it had been a date then... well, probably still no in this case as the conversion to and from a string would both use the same NLS-based format model - but it can still cause odd effects even then, and should be avoided on principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> data type is number(8)

Then you need to specify the format model for the conversion of that number to a date; instead of

```
to_date(max(mem.birth_date))
```

you need to do:

```
to_date(max(mem.birth_date), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

or even more explicitly:

```
to_date(to_char(max(mem.birth_date)), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

At the moment your code is relying on your current session's NLS settings to get the format model to use, and the error means it doesn't match the value you're passing. The reason your coworker is able to run the same query successfully is that their session has different NLS settings. This is why you shouldn't rely on NLS settings (or implicit conversions - they often go together) as you have no control over how other people will run your code.

You can see the effect with a cut-down example:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-RR';

with mem (birth_date) as (select 20190328 from dual)
select NVL(to_char(add_months(to_date(max(mem.birth_date)), + 780), 'yyyymmdd'), ' ')
from mem;

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

or even more simply:

```
with mem (birth_date) as (select 20190328 from dual)
select to_date(max(mem.birth_date))
from mem;

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Adding the format model produces a date:

```
with mem (birth_date) as (select 20190328 from dual)
select to_date(max(mem.birth_date), 'YYYYMMDD')
from mem;

TO_DATE(M
---------
28-Mar-19
```

and your adjustment and conversion works now too:

```
with mem (birth_date) as (select 20190328 from dual)
select NVL(to_char(add_months(to_date(max(mem.birth_date), 'YYYYMMDD'), + 780), 'yyyymmdd'), ' ')
from mem;

NVL(TO_C
--------
20840328
```

You should also store dates *as dates*, not as numbers, but that's a separate issue...

Comment: I am pretty sure that casper1111 will come back and say that he/she didn't design the database - it was someone else who decided that storing a date in a number would be a wise thing to do. Those people who do stuff like that are apparently never forced to live with their bad choices.

Comment: Yep, that's why it's a separate issue, and the answer isn't just "don't do that" - much as I would (too often) like it to be *8-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. @Alex Poole - thank you! - by adding 'yyyymmdd' after (mem.birth_date) fixed my issue! The line of code is now: select NVL(to_char(add_months(to_date(max(mem.birth_date), 'yyyymmdd'), + 780), 'yyyymmdd'), ' ') which works!

Comment: @Alex Poole It should have worked with to_date as well just making it to read in the format it is received like yyyymmdd or having a default dbms date format works as same. Whats your say on that though?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - that's what I've done - supplied the format model for the existing `to_date()` call. Setting the default (i.e. session) format model would still be relying on NLS settings - even if that's set in the same script the query runs in. It's better to avoid altogether.

Comment: Ohkay I get it Thanks @Alex Poole

Answer (score 0):

I guess an extra `to_char` must have resolved the problem just causing that number format be a character string and then using to_date and adding months would have worked.

`select NVL(to_char(add_months(to_date(to_char(max(mem.birth_date))), + 780), 'yyyymmdd'), ' ')`

Comment: No, `birth_date` is a number, so you're converting `max(mem.birth_date)` from a number to a string, which was already happening implicitly; and then converting that string to a date - still without supplying the proper format model. It will only work if `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` happens to be set to YYYYMMDD. So the colleague's session is set like that, but capser1111's session is set up differently. (So, don't rely on NLS... *8-)